# Long request processing with DropWizard

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard

I have a simple DropWizard service and I'd like a REST API to start a long running processing task - both CPU and I/O bound.  REST call will not wait for task completion, notification will happen by polling/long polling/web socket.

For now, I'd prefer if I can do this in Dropwizard and keep everything in single deployable JAR. What are my options?

UPDATE: I am interested in what my options are regarding running long running tasks in Dropwizard, deployed as single jar without external dependencies. Just spawn a new thread? Assuming there are just few such requests it would probably work but there should be better options.

Comment: stackoverflow is really for help with a specific problem, not helping you choose a design.  That being said, consider WebHooks.

Comment: @joakim-erdfelt - added more details to my original question, hopefully makes more sense now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want to use a managed resource:

https://dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/core.html#managed-objects

to setup a thread pool. Then, your initial request could push a message onto a queue. Your thread pool can pull messages off the queue and process them asynchronously.

You could maybe provide an additional endpoint so that clients can obtain the current state of the asynchronous process.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Are websockets are necessary for this case?

Comment: It's a pretty big project to give an example, you need to write front- and back-end components and the back-end needs to handle multiple requests. Which part specifically? I'm sure there are plenty of examples if you search around.

Comment: Websockets aren't 'necessary' - but it depends on your UI. You could just reload part of the screen to update the status.

Comment: I am interested in back-end part only, could you please take a look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653177/running-async-jobs-in-dropwizard-and-polling-their-status/34670685

Comment: The answer in your linked question is exactly what I would have written. If you need more help, then I think you need to show how far you've got, and ask a more specific problem.

Comment: Link is broken. Update it to http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html#man-core-managed ?