# Running async jobs in dropwizard, and polling their status

Tags: spring, jobs, dropwizard, jesque

In dropwizard, I need to implement asynchronous jobs and poll their status.
I have 2 endpoints for this in resource:

```
@Path("/jobs")
@Component
public class MyController {
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String startJob(@Valid MyRequest request) {
        return 1111;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{jobId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JobStatus getJobStatus(@PathParam("id") String jobId) {
        return JobStatus.READY;
    }
}
```

I am considering to use quartz to start job, but only single time and without repeating. And when requesting status, I will get trigger status. But the idea of using quartz for none-scheduled usage looks weird.
Is there any better approaches for this? Maybe dropwizard provides better tools itself? Will appriciate any advices.

UPDATE: I also looking at https://github.com/gresrun/jesque, but can not find any way to poll the status of running job.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `Managed` interface. In the snippet below I am using the `ScheduledExecutorService` to exuecute jobs, but you can use `Quartz` instead if you like. I prefer working with `ScheduledExecutorService` as it is simpler and easier...

first step is to register your managed service.

```
environment.lifecycle().manage(new JobExecutionService());
```

Second step is to write it.

```
/**
 * A wrapper around the   ScheduledExecutorService so all jobs can start when the server starts, and
 * automatically shutdown when the server stops.
 * @author Nasir Rasul {@literal nasir@rasul.ca}
 */
public class JobExecutionService implements Managed {


    private final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting jobs");
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new HelloWorldJob(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Shutting down");
        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```

and the job itself

```
/**
 * A very simple job which just prints the current time in millisecods
 * @author Nasir Rasul {@literal nasir@rasul.ca}
 */
public class HelloWorldJob implements Runnable {
    /**
     * When an object implementing interface <code>Runnable</code> is used
     * to create a thread, starting the thread causes the object's
     * <code>run</code> method to be called in that separately executing
     * thread.
     * <p>
     * The general contract of the method <code>run</code> is that it may
     * take any action whatsoever.
     *
     * @see Thread#run()
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comment below, if you use `Runnable`, you can `Thread.getState()`. Please refer to [Get a List of all Threads currently running in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java). You may still need some intermediary pieces depending on how you're wiring you application.

Comment: Thanks for response. But how I will get the status of running job in this case? When user will send POST to "/jobs", the job will be started and the job id will be returned. When user will send "/jobs/<jobid>", the job status should be returned - whether it's still running or not.

Comment: @me1111 If you use the `Runnable`, you can use the regular `Thread.getState()`. You might have to piece something together to make it work end to end but all the necessary pieces are available. Get a list of all threads (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java) and then call their state method.